# Get more than 1 quotations in text paragraph in R regex

Tags: regex, r, lookbehind

First: Find the texts that are inside the quotations "I want everything inside here".

Second: To extract 1 sentence before quotation.

I would like to achieve this output desirable by look behind regex in R if possible

Example:

```
Yoyo. He is sad. Oh no! "Don't sad!" Yeah: "Testing...  testings," Boys. Sun. Tree... 0.2% green,"LL" "WADD" HOLA.
```

Desired Output:

```
[1] Oh no! "Don't sad!"
[2] Yeah: "Testing... testings"
[3] Tree... 0.2% green, "LL"
[4] Tree... 0.2% green, "LL" "WADD"
```

dput:

```
"Yoyo. He is sad. Oh no! \"Don't sad!\" Yeah: \"Testing...  testings,\" Boys. Sun. Tree... 0.2% green,\"LL\" \"WAAD\" HOLA."
```

Tried using this but can't work:

```
str_extract(t, "(?<=\\.\\s)[^.:]*[.:]\\s*\"[^\"]*\"")
```

Also tried:

```
regmatches(t , gregexpr('^[^\\.]+[\\.\\,\\:]\\s+(.*(?:\"[^\"]+\\")).*$', t))

regmatches(t , gregexpr('\"[^\"]*\"(?<=\\s[.?][^\\.\\s])', t))
```

Tried your method @naurel:

```
> regmatches(t, regexpr("(?:\"? *([^\"]*))(\"[^\"]*\")", t, perl=T))
[1] " Yoyo. He is sad. Oh no! \"Don't sad!\""
```

Comment: You failed to specify the requirement.

Comment: What you mean by that? @AvinashRaj

Comment: I tried using your method just now, but cannot work, please help. thanks @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want the last sentence I've cleared the regex for you : [result](https://regex101.com/r/pU6qK7/3)

Explanation :
First you're looking for something that is between quotes. And if there is multiples quotes successively you want them to match as one.

```
(\"[^\"]*\"(?: *\"[^\"]*\")*)
```

Does the trick. Then you want to match the sentence before this group. A sentence is starting with a CAPITAL letter. So we will start the match to the first capital encounter before the previously defined group (ie : not followed by any other CAPITAL letter)

```
([A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W\s])*)
```

Put it togeither and you obtain :

```
([A-Z](?:[a-z0-9\W\s])*)(\"[^\"]*\"(?: *\"[^\"]*\")*)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried. But still can't work @naurel

Comment: Ho didn't notice you wanted just the last phrase let me correct it.

Comment: Thanks. The desired output is in my question.

Comment: I'm not able to do it since the wanted delimiter is a dot and you have too many exception (3dots in row, when it's a pourcentage, and maybe many more not described here). Sorry. The best I can think for you is to use my solution and then to rerun a regex on the primary group to match the only last phrase (including all your exceptions)

Comment: Have you updated the solution? Because I tried, I still get the same result. You can forget about the 3 dots first. I just want to first look at quotations, then to extract the sentence before that. @naurel

Comment: Can you please help me. Thanks @naurel

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to how to extract a sentence before the FULLSTOP instead of capital letter? As sometimes for example, hello. How are you, TGIF. "hah", then it will stop at TGIF instead at How. @naurel